# Do mounting motors at different height each other has any impact on performances?

Tags: quadcopters, design

Multirotor motors are typically mounted on same height.
I'm wondering what should I expect if they are mounted at different eights each other.

Model will work exactly in the same way as if they are on same level or there is some significant impact on model dynamic?

For better clarity take in account the following arrangement cases for a quadcopter:

**CASE A**

Different height levels between front motors and back motors mount. So, a CW motor and a CCW motor with related propellers are on arms at height *H1*, and a CW and CCW motor and related propellers are at another height *H2*.

**CASE B**

Different height level between CW motors and CCW motors. So, both CW motors on arms at height *H1* and both CCW motors are at another height *H2*.

Comment: Of course it does...you have a good discussion on the topic between Le Drib and someone else on YouTube...the title of the video is "5 begginer FpV mistakes" by Rotor Riot if I remember correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designs with different height motors are generally aiming to increase the separation of the airflow through front motors and rear motors. As the quad flies forwards, the rear motors enter air that has been disturbed by the front motors. Lifting the rear motors theoretically puts them in cleaner air, increasing efficiency.

Motors are generally at the same height to simplify frame design, as the highest stresses are found between the motors. Attempting to pass these stresses between the top and bottom plate requires extra frame material, which generally outweighs any aerodynamic gains.